# How do you explain this div spacing issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This spacing issue was driving me crazy. I finally figured out that in order to have spaces between the form elements, I need to format my HTML code as shown below.

Could somebody explain what's going on here? Is this some newline issue?

**Notes:**

- I'm using Bootstrap 3 CSS file, no other styling in place
- the only difference between the 2 samples below is in how `.form-group` divs are laid out

**1. Form elements with spaces:**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elements with spaces</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**2. Form elements without spaces:**

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Elements with spaces</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div><div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: They are probably `inline-block` elements..

Comment: Could you post the css for .formgroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space in your code. Since you have divs in your example which are normally block level elements, but they're appearing side by side, your CSS is most likely changing them to display inline. You could also remove the gap by using HTML comments.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div><!--
  --><div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline), `form-group` is used to wrap the `form-control` so your 2nd approach is better.

Your 1st example is rendering as expected since the Bootstrap CSS sets `inline-block` and no margin on the `form-control` itself. You could override this behavior by using margin in the CSS..

```
.form-inline .form-control {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:4px;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/86947

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to j08691 answer, this is the method I use to prevent white-space:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
</div
><div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

You don't introduce unnecessary comments, but auto-formatting in some IDEs might mess up your indentation a bit.